# AWS Step Functions, exiting workflow unexpectedly after interating a few times

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have attached the Workflow as it was rendered on AWS. Basically, I am triggering this State Machine from API Gateway. However for testing purposes, I set my "Wait for an hour" Step to only wait 60 seconds. Everything seems to be in order, and it is probably because I am a noob.

When it is triggered, it will run the cycle of waiting, then re-triggering the lambda 5 for 5 iterations, then exit unexpectedly.

If I set timeout for 3600 seconds, it does not iterate more than once.

If I manually trigger the Statemachine, it will run for ~2 mintues with

```
Express execution is running...
```

then give me the following message

```
StartSyncExecution call failed.
There was an error calling StartSyncExecution. Refresh the page to try again.
```

However the CloudWatch logs do not indicate anything as gone awry, it simply says "WaitStateEntered" then continues on after the allotted timeout.

This is an express workflow and here is my statemachine in its current state. Pun intended.

```
{
  "Comment": "State machine for repeated notification until duplicate is resolved",
  "StartAt": "accountDuplicationFind Lambda",
  "States": {
    "accountDuplicationFind Lambda": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "TimeoutSeconds": 6200,
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "FunctionName": "READACTED"
      },
      "Next": "Duplicates Found?",
      "Comment": "Invoke the accountDuplicationFind.js in the Account Microservice"
    },
    "Duplicates Found?": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.body",
          "StringMatches": "Duplication Notifications Sent",
          "Next": "Wait for an hour",
          "Comment": "If Duplicates have been found move to wait"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.body",
          "StringMatches": "No Reported Duplicates",
          "Next": "Success"
        }
      ],
      "Comment": "Either exit or restart the process according to whether there are dups or not "
    },
    "Wait for an hour": {
      "Type": "Wait",
      "Seconds": 60,
      "Next": "accountDuplicationFind Lambda",
      "Comment": "Wait for 1 hour to notify again"
    },
    "Success": {
      "Type": "Succeed"
    }
  }
}
```

[image: rendered aws step function workflow]

Comment: Debugging suggestion:  copy your Sfn definition into a StandardWorkflow.  You can see step-by-step execution progress (timings, input, output, exceptions) right in the console.  I develop in Standard and deploy in Express for this reason.   Another tip:  consider a Default branch in your [Choice State](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html) to prevent deadlock if neither Rule1 or Rule2 matches.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to refine the workflow as Standard rather than Express, also made sure to take note to make one of my choices a default, and it is working as expected!

Answer (score 0):

I refined the Step Function as a Standard Workflow, rather than an Express Workflow and that seems to have solved my issue!